# PHP PDO Database Abstraction Layer

Tags: php, security, pdo

I'd like to get some feedback on a PHP Database Abstraction Layer I've created. It's a little long, but there really wasn't a way to just post part of it. Here is the base `DBObject` class for MySQL:

```
<?php
/**
 * Description: The DBObject class is the generic database object. It is not to be used directly, but extended
 * by additional classes, each corresponding to a database table. This particular DBObject is for use with a 
 * MySQL PDO driver.
 * Dependencies: A database connection script that uses the MySQL PDO extension
 * Requirements: PHP 5.2 or higher
 */
class DBObject {

    protected $alias = NULL;
    protected $boundValues = array();
    protected $db;
    protected $fields = array();
    protected $groupBy = NULL;
    protected $having = NULL;
    protected $joins = NULL;    
    protected $limit = NULL;
    protected $numBoundValues = 0;
    protected $offset = NULL;
    protected $orderBy = NULL;
    protected $patterns = array();
    protected $prefix;  
    protected $selectList = NULL;
    protected $table;
    protected $tablePrefix = NULL;
    protected $unions = array();
    protected $valueStorage = array();
    protected $where = NULL;

    /**
     * @param object $db - The PDO database connection object
     * @param string $table - The name of the table
     * @param array $fields - The names of each field in the table
     * @param string $schema - The schema
     * @param $prefix - optional - A prefix for the table
     * @return The object for chaining 
     */
    function __construct(PDO $db, $table, array $fields, $schema, $prefix = NULL){
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->prefix = $prefix;
        $this->tablePrefix = ($prefix) ? $prefix.$table : $table;
        $this->table = $table;      
        foreach($fields as $key) {
            $this->fields[$key] = NULL;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $key - The table column name to retrieve 
     * @return mixed - The value of the key, if the key exists, FALSE otherwise
     */
    function __get($key){
        return (array_key_exists($key, $this->valueStorage)) ? $this->valueStorage[$key] : FALSE;       
    }

    /**
     * @param string $key - The table column name to be assigned a value
     * @param $value - The value to assign to the key
     * @return boolean - TRUE if the key exists, FALSE otherwise
     */
    function __set($key, $value){
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->fields)){
            $this->valueStorage[$key] = $value;
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds a value to be bound on query execution
     * @param mixed $value - The value(s) to be bound
     * @return string - The named value placeholder
     */
    protected function addBoundValue($value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            $valueNames = array();
            foreach ($value as $val){
                $this->numBoundValues += 1;
                $valueName = ':'.$this->numBoundValues;
                $this->boundValues[$valueName] = $val;
                $this->patterns[] = '#(\s'.$valueName.'[\s]?)#';
                $valueNames[] = $valueName;
            }
            return $valueNames;         
        } else {
            $this->numBoundValues += 1;
            $valueName = ':'.$this->numBoundValues;
            $this->boundValues[$valueName] = $value;
            $this->patterns[] = '#(\s'.$valueName.'[\s]?)#';
            return $valueName;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds space separators to each bound value
     * @return array - The spaced bound values
     */
    protected function getSpacedBoundValues(){
        $boundValues = ' '.implode(' | ', $this->boundValues).' ';
        return explode('|', $boundValues);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $alias - Sets the alias for the main table. Optional for query build.
     * @return The object for chaining  
     */
    public function alias($alias) {
        $this->alias = $alias;
        return $this;
    }   

    /**
     * @var array $selectList - Used for determining which database fields should be selected. Fields from joins may be included,
     *  but must include either the full table name or alias as a prefix. 
     * @return The object for chaining
     */
    public function selectList(array $selectList) {
        foreach($selectList as $value) {
            $this->selectList[] = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $quotable - Escapes an input variable for use in an SQL query. Returns the escaped string. Optional for query build.
     * @return The escaped input
     */
    public function quote($quotable) {
        return $this->db->quote($quotable);
    }

    /**
     * Joins will be added to the join array and processed in their array order and use the ON syntax 
     *  rather than USING. Optional for query build.
     * @param string $joinType -The type of join to be performed. Acceptable values are 'left', 'right', 'inner', and 'full'
     * @param string $table - The name of the table to be joined with the current table
     * @param string $column - The column(s) to be compared to the value
     * @param string $operator - The operator to be used in the comparison
     * @param string $value - The value to which $column is compared
     * @param string $tableAlias - optional - The alias of the joined table. If not set, alias defaults to the table name
     * @return The object for chaining
     */
    public function addJoin($joinType, $table, $column, $operator, $value, $tableAlias=NULL){
        $joinAlias = ($tableAlias) ? $tableAlias : $table;
        $joinName = ($this->prefix) ? $this->prefix.$table : $table;
        $expr = "$column $operator $value"; 
        switch (strtolower($joinType)) {
            case "left":
                $this->joins[] = " LEFT JOIN $joinName AS $joinAlias ON $expr";
                break;
            case "right":
                $this->joins[] = " RIGHT JOIN $joinName AS $joinAlias ON $expr";
                break;                  
            case "inner":
                $this->joins[] = " INNER JOIN $joinName AS $joinAlias ON $expr";
                break;
            case "full":
                $this->joins[] = " FULL JOIN $joinName AS $joinAlias ON $expr";
                break;
            default:
                throw new Vm_Db_Exception("'$joinType' is not a supported join type.");
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a where clause.  Optional for query build.
     * @param string $column - The column(s) to be compared to the value
     * @param string $operator - The operator to be used in the comparison. 
     * @param mixed $value - The value to which $column is compared - If multiple values are entered as an array, they will be wrapped in parentheses, else use a string
     * @param string (optional) $antecedent - The operator preceding the WHERE clause. Acceptable values are 'AND' and 'OR' 
     * @param string (optional) $paren - Adds a paren to the WHERE clause - 'open', 'close', 'both'
     * @param boolean $caseSensitive - optional - Whether or not the clause should be case sensitive, defaults TRUE. If FALSE, will use UTF8_GENERAL_CI
     * @param boolean $bind - optional - Whether or not $value should be a bound parameter, defaults TRUE. Use FALSE when $value is a subquery
     * @return The object for chaining
     */
    public function where($column, $operator, $value, $antecedent=NULL, $paren=NULL, $caseSensitive = TRUE, $bind = TRUE){
        $value = ($bind) ? $this->addBoundValue($value) : $value;
        $value = (is_array($value)) ? '( '.implode(', ', $value).')' : $value;
        $operator = ($caseSensitive) ? $operator : 'COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI '.$operator;
        switch ($paren){
            case 'open':
                $this->where[] = ($antecedent) ? " $antecedent ($column $operator $value" : " ($column $operator $value";
                break;
            case 'close':
                $this->where[] = ($antecedent) ? " $antecedent $column $operator $value)" : " $column $operator $value)";
                break;
            case 'both':
                $this->where[] = ($antecedent) ? " $antecedent ($column $operator $value)" : " ($column $operator $value)";
                break;                      
            default:
                $this->where[] = ($antecedent) ? " $antecedent $column $operator $value" : " $column $operator $value";             
        }
        return $this;       
    }

    /**
     * @param array $groupBy - The fields by which the result set should be grouped. Optional for query build.
     * @return The object for chaining
     */
    public function groupBy(array $groupBy) {
        foreach($groupBy as $value) {
            $this->groupBy[] = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a HAVING clause.  Optional for query build. MUST be used in conjunction with the GROUP BY clause
     * @param string $column - The column(s) to be compared to the value. Note: The column is not a bound parameter in this clause
     * @param string $operator - The operator to be used in the comparison
     * @param string $value - The value to which $column is compared
     * @param string $antecedent - optional - The operator preceding the HAVING clause. Acceptable values are 'AND' and 'OR'
     * @param string $function - optional - The SQL function to apply to the column
     * @return The object for chaining 
     */
    public function having($column, $operator, $value, $antecedent=NULL, $function=NULL) {
        $column = $this->addBoundValue($column);
        $column = ($function) ? "$function( $column)" : $column;
        $value = $this->addBoundValue($value);
        $this->having[] = ($antecedent) ? " $antecedent $column $operator $value" : "$column $operator $value";
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Orders the query.  Optional for query build
     * @param string $field - The field to sort by
     * @param string $sort (optional) - The sort type. Acceptable values are ASC and DESC
     * @param boolean $caseSensitive - optional - Whether or not the ordering should be case sensitive, defaults TRUE. If FALSE, will use UTF8_GENERAL_CI
     * @return The object for chaining
     */
    public function orderBy($field, $sort=NULL, $caseSensitive=TRUE){
        $sort = (strtolower($sort) == 'desc') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
        $sort = ($caseSensitive) ? $sort : 'COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI '.$sort;
        $this->orderBy[] = ' '.$field." $sort";
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $limit - The limit of the result set.  Optional for query build.
     * @return The object for chaining
     */
    public function limit($limit) {
        if (!is_int($limit)){
            throw new Vm_Db_Exception('Limit must be an integer');
        }
        $this->limit = ($limit != 0) ? $limit : NULL;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $offset - The offset of the result set.  Optional for query build.
     * @return The object for chaining
     */
    public function offset($offset) {
        if (!is_int($offset)){
            throw new Vm_Db_Exception('Offset must be an integer');
        }
        $this->offset = ($offset != 0) ? $offset : NULL;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Clears all class variables by setting them to NULL, allow class instance reuse
     * @param boolean $clearBound - optional - Whether or not the bound variables should be cleared, defaults TRUE
     */
    public function clear($clearBound = TRUE) {
        $this->valueStorage = NULL;
        $this->selectList = NULL;
        $this->alias = NULL;
        $this->joins = NULL;
        $this->where = NULL;
        $this->groupBy = NULL;  
        $this->having = NULL;           
        $this->orderBy = NULL;
        $this->limit = NULL;
        $this->offset = NULL;
        if ($clearBound){
            $this->boundValues = NULL;
            $this->numBoundValues = 0;
        }
    } 

    /**
     * Compiles the given data into a select query and returns a result set based on the query
     * @param string (optional) $mode - 
     * If set to 'single', returns a single result set which may be accessed through magic methods.
     * 
     * Example: $user->name or $user->{'name'} 
     *
     * If set to 'assoc', will return the result set as an associative array, which can be accessed through 
     * a foreach loop
     *
     * Example: foreach ($user->select("assoc") as $row) {
     *              echo "ID = ".$row['userId']."\t";
     *              echo "Type = ".$row['firstName']."\t";
     *              echo "Parent = ".$row['lastName']."<br>";
     *          }
     *
     * If set to 'num', will return the result set as a numerical array
     *
     * If set to 'obj', will return an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column 
     * names returned in your result set
     *
     * If set to 'lazy', will return a combination of 'both' and 'obj', creating the object variable names 
     * as they are accessed
     *
     * If set to 'subquery', will wrap the query in parentheses and return it for use in a subquery without executing it.
     *  WARNING: Bound parameters are not used for subqueries 
     *
     * If set to "count", will return the number of rows
     *
     * Example: $number = $user->select("count");
     *
     * If set to "union", will add the query to the unions array. Note: you must reuse the object to use union.
     * 
     * Example:
     * 
     * $user = new Db_User($db);
     * 
     * //First Query
     * $user->where('lastName', '=', 'Jones');
     * $user->select('union');
     * 
     * //Second Query
     * $user->where('lastName', '=', 'Smith');
     * $user->select('union');
     * 
     * //Get union results (orderBy and limit are optional)
     * $user->orderBy('lastName', 'ASC');
     * $user->orderBy('firstName', 'ASC');
     * $user->limit(25);
     * $users = $user->select('assoc');
     *
     * If set to "debug", prints the compiled query
     *
     * Example: $user->select->("debug"); 
     *
     * If left unset, the default return set is 'both', which returns the combination of both an associative array
     * and a numerical array
     * @param string $selectType - optional - 'DISTINCT' or 'ALL'. Note: $selectType is ignored for the first select query in a set of unions
     * @return mixed - The query result set
     */
    public function select($mode=NULL, $selectType=NULL) {
        if ($selectType){
            $type = ($selectType == 'ALL') ? ' ALL' : ' DISTINCT';
        } else {
            $type = NULL;
        }

        $selectList = ($this->selectList) ? ' '.implode(', ', $this->selectList) : ' *';
        $alias = ($this->alias) ? ' AS '.$this->alias : ' AS '.$this->table;    
        $joins = ($this->joins) ? implode('', $this->joins) : NULL;
        $where = ($this->where) ? ' WHERE'.implode('', $this->where) : NULL;

        if (!$this->groupBy) {
            $groupBy = NULL;
            $having = NULL; 
        } else {
            $groupBy = ' GROUP BY '.implode(', ', $this->groupBy);
            $having = ($this->having) ? ' HAVING '.implode('', $this->having) : NULL;
        }

        $orderBy = ($this->orderBy) ? ' ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $this->orderBy) : NULL;

        if ($this->limit) {
            $limit = ($this->offset) ? ' LIMIT '.$this->offset.', '.$this->limit : ' LIMIT '.$this->limit;
        } else {
            $limit = NULL;
        }

        if ((sizeof($this->unions) > 0)&&($mode != 'union')){
            $query = implode(' ', $this->unions)."$orderBy$limit";
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT$type$selectList FROM ".$this->tablePrefix."$alias$joins$where$groupBy$having$orderBy$limit";
        }
        $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

        if ((is_array($this->boundValues))&&(!in_array($mode, array('subquery', 'union')))){
            foreach ($this->boundValues as $name=>$value) {
                $result->bindValue($name, $value);
            }
        }

        if (strtolower($mode) == "debug") {
            return preg_replace($this->patterns, $this->getSpacedBoundValues(), $result->queryString, 1);
        } else if (strtolower($mode) == "subquery") {
            $this->clear(FALSE);
            return '('.$result->queryString.')';
        } else if (strtolower($mode) == "union") {
            $this->clear(FALSE);
            $this->unions[] = (sizeof($this->unions) >= 1) ? "UNION $selectType (".$result->queryString.')' : '('.$result->queryString.')';         
        } else {
            $result->execute();

            switch (strtolower($mode)) {
                case "assoc":
                    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                case "count":
                    return count($result->fetchAll());
                case "num":
                    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
                case "lazy":
                    return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
                case "obj":
                    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                case "single":
                    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    if (is_array($rows)){
                        foreach(array_keys($rows) as $key) {
                            $this->valueStorage[$key] = $rows[$key];
                        }
                    }
                    return $rows;                   
                default:
                    return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);  
            }
        }
    } 

    /**
     * The insert function inserts records into the database. Magic methods are used to insert
     *  values into each field. Fields that are not assigned a value will not be included in the compiled query.
     * Example usage: 
     *      $users = new Db_Users($db);
     *      $users->username = 'jDoe';
     *      $users->firstName = 'John';
     *      $users->{'lastName'} = 'Doe'; //An alternate syntax
     *      $users->{'age'} = 37;
     *      $users->insert();
     * @param string $mode - optional - 
     *  If set to 'debug', returns the compiled SQL query 
     * @return mixed - The last insert id if the query is successful, the compiled query if mode is set to debug, 
     *  FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function insert($mode=NULL) {
        $valueTypes = array('array'=>FALSE, 'single'=>FALSE);
        $arrayLength = 0;
        $fieldNames = array();
        $values = array();
        $params = array();

        foreach ($this->valueStorage as $name=>$value) {
            $fieldNames[] = $name;
            if (is_array($value)){
                if (!$valueTypes['array']){
                    $valueTypes['array'] = TRUE;
                }
                if ($valueTypes['single']) {
                    throw new Vm_Db_Exception('Insert values must be either arrays of the same length or a single value');
                }   
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($value as $inputValue){
                    $params[$i][] = '?';
                    $values[$i][] = $inputValue;
                    $i++;
                }
            } else {
                if (!$valueTypes['single']){
                    $valueTypes['single'] = TRUE;
                }
                if ($valueTypes['array']) {
                    throw new Vm_Db_Exception('Insert values must be either arrays of the same length or a single value');
                }
                $params[0][] = '?';
                $values[0][] = $value;
            }
        }
        $numInserts = 0;
        foreach ($params as $count=>$value){
            $params[$count] = '('.implode(',', $value).')';
            $numInserts += 1;
        }
        $params = implode(',', $params);

        $numValues = sizeof($values[0]);
        $boundValues = array();
        foreach ($values as $value){
            if (sizeof($value) != $numValues){
                throw new Vm_Db_Exception('Insert values must be either arrays of the same length or a single value');
            }
            foreach ($value as $boundValue){
                $boundValues[] = $boundValue;
            }
        }

        $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->tablePrefix.' ('.implode(',', $fieldNames).') VALUES '.$params;
        $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

        if (strtolower($mode) == 'debug') {
            $patterns = array();
            foreach ($boundValues as $value){
                $patterns[] = '#\?#';
            }
            return preg_replace($patterns, $boundValues, $result->queryString, 1);
        } else {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($boundValues as $value){
                $boundValues[$i] = $boundValues[$i];
                $result->bindValue(($i+1), $boundValues[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
            $result->execute();
            return $this->db->lastInsertId() + $numInserts - 1;
        }
    } 

    /**
     * Updates a database field with values obtained from magic methods representing the field names. 
     * Notes: Multiple table updates are currently not supported, nor are ordering or limiting result sets due to
     *  DBMS syntax inconsistencies
     * @param string $mode - optional - If set to 'debug', returns the compiled SQL query
     * @return int - The number of affected rows 
     */
    public function update($mode=NULL) {
        $fields = array();
        $boundValues = array();

        foreach (array_keys($this->valueStorage) as $field) {
            $fields[]= "$field=";
        }
        $parameters = implode("?, ", $fields).'?';

        $i = 1;
        foreach (array_keys($this->valueStorage) as $field){
            $boundValues[$i]= $this->valueStorage[$field];
            $i++;
        }

        $where = ($this->where) ? ' WHERE'.implode('', $this->where) : NULL;
        $where = preg_replace('#(\s:[\w-]+[\s]?)#', ' ? ', $where);
        $boundValues = array_merge($boundValues, array_values($this->boundValues));
        $boundValues = $boundValues;

        $query = "UPDATE ".$this->tablePrefix." SET $parameters$where";
        $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

        if (strtolower($mode) == 'debug') {
            $patterns = array();
            foreach ($boundValues as $value){
                $patterns[] = '#\?#';
            }
            return preg_replace($patterns, $boundValues, $result->queryString, 1);
        } else {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($boundValues as $value){
                $boundValues[$i] = $boundValues[$i];
                $result->bindValue($i+1, $boundValues[$i]);
                $i++;
            }
            $result->execute();
            return $result->rowCount();
        }
    } 

    /**
     * The delete function deletes all rows that meet the conditions specified in the where clause
     *  and returns the number of affected rows
     * @param string $mode - optional - Acceptable value is 'debug', which prints the compiled query
     */
    public function delete($mode=NULL) {
        $where = ($this->where) ? ' WHERE'.implode('', $this->where) : NULL;
        $query = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->tablePrefix.$where;
        $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

        if (strtolower($mode) == 'debug') {
            return preg_replace($this->patterns, $this->getSpacedBoundValues(), $result->queryString, 1);
        } else {
            foreach ($this->boundValues as $name=>$value) {
                $result->bindValue($name, $value);
            }
            $result->execute();
            return $result->rowCount();
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Description: Deletes all rows in the table, returns the number of affected rows.
     * @return int - The number of affected rows
     */
    public function deleteAll(){
        $result = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM '.$this->tablePrefix);
        $result->execute();
        return $result->rowCount();
    } 
}
?>
```

The `DBObject` class is meant to be extended by additional classes, one for each table in the database. As an example, here are two for pages and comments:

```
<?php
class Db_Pages extends DBObject {
    function __construct($db, $prefix = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($db, 'pages', array('pageId', 'pageTitle', 'pageCreationDate', 'pageContent'), 'public', $prefix);
    }
}
?>
```

And:

```
<?php
class Db_Comments extends DBObject {
    function __construct($db, $prefix = NULL) {
        parent::__construct($db, 'comments', array('commentId', 'pageId', 'commentDate', 'comment'), 'public', $prefix);
    }
}
?>
```

The extending classes are the classes you would actually use in your code. Here's an example of how you would create a new page:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$page = new Db_Pages($db);
$page->pageTitle = 'Sample Page Title';
$page->pageContent = 'This is the content for the sample page';
$page->insert();
```

Create multiple pages:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$page = new Db_Pages($db);
$page->pageTitle = array('Sample Page Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3');
$page->pageContent = array('This is the content for the sample page', 'Content 2', 'Content 3');
$page->insert();
```

Here is how you would access a single page:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$page = new Db_Pages($db);
$page->where('pageId', '=', 1);
$page->select('single');

echo $page->pageTitle;
echo $page->pageContent;
```

Or multiple pages:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$page = new Db_Pages($db);
$pages = $page->select('assoc');

foreach($pages as $page){
     echo $page['pageTitle'];
     echo $page['pageContent'];
}
```

Update a page:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$page = new Db_Pages($db);
$page->where('pageId', '=', 1);
$page->pageTitle = 'New Page Title';
$page->update();
```

Delete a page:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$page = new Db_Pages($db);
$page->where('pageId', '=', 1);
$page->delete();
```

Get comments for a page, sorted by date:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$comments = new Db_Comments($db);
$comments->alias('c');
$comments->selectList(array('c.commentDate', 'c.comment'));
$comments->addJoin('left', 'pages', 'c.pageId', '=', 'p.pageId', 'p');
$comments->where('p.pageId', '=', 1);
$comments->orderBy('c.commentDate', 'ASC');
$commentList = $comments->select('assoc');

foreach ($commentList as $comment){
     echo $comment['commentDate'];
     echo $comment['comment'];
}
```

If you prefer a less verbose syntax, you can also chain the clause functions together:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$comments = new Db_Comments($db)
     ->alias('c')
     ->selectList(array('c.commentDate', 'c.comment'))
     ->addJoin('left', 'pages', 'c.pageId', '=', 'p.pageId', 'p')
     ->where('p.pageId', '=', 1)
     ->orderBy('c.commentDate', 'ASC');
$commentList = $comments->select('assoc');

foreach ($commentList as $comment){
     echo $comment['commentDate'];
     echo $comment['comment'];
}
```

If you want to debug your SQL statement:

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$page = new Db_Pages($db);
$page->where('pageId', '=', 1);
echo $page->select('debug');
//Prints: SELECT * FROM 'pages' WHERE 'pageId' = 1
```

The DB class can also handle `LIMIT`, `GROUPBY`, Offset & `HAVING` clauses, subqueries, other types of `join`s, and `union`s. It uses PDO and all inputs are bound parameters automatically.

The `DBObject` above is for MySQL only, but I am creating other `DBObject` classes for other DB types as well, with the idea of being able to substitute one DB type for another without have to change any of the application code (just load the `DBObject` for that DB type).

All of the extending DB classes like `Db_Pages` and `Db_Comments` can be generated automatically. I have a separate class for database operations like creating or editing new tables, etc. that functions in a similar manner as `DBObject`.

Comment: Well, what benefit does this have over the major ORM systems (Or PEAR DB_Object if we want something closer to your implementation)?

Comment: Pear DB_DataObject is for PHP 4 and this is PHP 5+. This uses PDO, so all the parameters are bound and injection-safe. Also, it will allow your application to support multiple database types without requiring a rewrite of your code. Just swap the MySQL DB_Object out with whatever database type you want to use. I'd like to think using it is pretty easy as well.

Comment: As PDO is OOPlicious itself, did you consider extending the PDO classes instead of creating your own base class? I think it would save you some effort, and also make it possible for users of the class to fall back to PDO's methods if doing so would make certain tasks easier than using your class's.

Comment: @GarrettAlbright - I did consider that, but chose to pass it in through the constructor instead. Users can still access it that way if they need to, but if PDO was extended, I would have had to connect to the database each time a query was executed. This way, I connect once and just pass that connection in.

Comment: What is the license for your code? Did you intend to release it in an Open Source license MIT or BSD like?

Comment: Something that'd make me want to use it is if you implemented validation. The best solution I can think of is allowing the user to add a method like `(bool) validationPageId($string)` to `class Db_Pages extends DBObject`, which would then automatically be called and generate an error/throw an exception.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen - Thanks for the suggestion. It's an interesting idea, but I think I'd prefer to keep the validation separate. However, you could implement an ActiveRecord-type of layer on top of the Db_Pages class (`class Pages extends Db_Pages` or Pages could simply use Db_Pages rather than extending it). Pages would have methods like newPage($id, $title, $content), getPage($id), deletePage($id), etc. That would be a great place to handle validation and exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, your suggestion is better. I just hate having to handle validation at all. It'd be great if it'd all be taken care of without you really noticed it.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen - That would definitely be cool, but it would be extremely difficult to pull off as no two databases are exactly the same. I really don't know where I would begin to try to abstract something like that.

Comment: excuse me but can your pdo support the usage of IN? i tried, but it returns as uncaught exception error.
//$dt range is a string variable holding value such as ('2012-01-01','2011-01-01') `$test->where('date','IN',$dtrange);
$test->where('Used','=','Yes','AND');
$test->orderBy('date');
$tests=$test->select('assoc');`

Comment: @MrGan - Try making $dtrange an array with the values you listed without the parentheses. `$test->where('date','IN',array('2012-01-01','2011-01-01'));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty ambitious chunk of code, but it looks pretty well done.

I like your variable names, the are nice and expressive.  Too many developers these days seem to take variable naming for granted.

One thing I'd suggest is to make the users of your API think even less.  I'd create a few convenience methods for different types of joins like so:

```
addLeftJoin($table, $column, $operator, $value, $tableAlias=NULL){
    return addJoin("left", $table, $column, $operator, $value, $tableAlias=NULL);
}

addRightJoin($table, $column, $operator, $value, $tableAlias=NULL){
    ...
}

addInnerJoin($table, $column, $operator, $value, $tableAlias=NULL){
    ...
}

addFullJoin($table, $column, $operator, $value, $tableAlias=NULL){
    ...
}
```

If you do this you could even hide the implementation if your addJoin which will give you more felxability to change it in the future, as long as your convenience method's dont change their signatures none of the users of your API see a differenece.

Looks like you are doing some good error checking in most places, but I do see a possible place for an error in your "where" and "having" functions, it looks like somebody can pass in an any string as an operator that would make the query crash.

```
//$db = the PDO database connection
$page = new Db_Pages($db);
$page->where('pageId', 'foo', 1); //crash
```

You might also want to consider checking the column array when somebody adds a column to the groupby function to make sure that the sql is valid.

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. This was the kind of answer I was hoping for and your suggestions are very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, it's a huge work, so, I'll try to do this by iteration, adding then when I've a little time.

I'll start with the form.

**Iteration 1**
*Readability:*

Thereafter is the code with some improvements about it's readability.

I've limited the width to 78 columns, use 2 spaces soft tabs instead of 4, add a line feed (and indentation) before `{`, etc.

IMHO, 2 spaces soft tab make easier the target of 78 columns, so I prefer it to the conventional 4 spaces soft tab.

I like to target 78 columns because the target is generally 80. But some repositories with very strict commitment rules can block you when they considers a `lf` like a character, or a `crlf` like two.

As you can see, it also bring the advantage to not have an horizontal slider here.

One important thing: I've deleted the `?>` at the end of the file, for the same reasons as those of the [Zend Framework PHP File Formatting convention](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html):

> For files that contain only PHP code, the closing tag ("?>") is never permitted. It is not required by PHP, and omitting it´ prevents the accidental injection of trailing white space into the response.

It's just my vision of a more readable code, and it will help me for further iteration if I found some time for it...

```
<?php
/**
 * Description: The DBObject class is the generic database object. It is not
 * to be used directly, but extended by additional classes, each
 * corresponding to a database table. This particular DBObject is for use
 * with a MySQL PDO driver.
 * Dependencies: A database connection script that uses the MySQL PDO
 * extension
 * Requirements: PHP 5.2 or higher
 */
class DBObject {

  protected $alias = NULL;
  protected $boundValues = array();
  protected $db;
  protected $fields = array();
  protected $groupBy = NULL;
  protected $having = NULL;
  protected $joins = NULL;    
  protected $limit = NULL;
  protected $numBoundValues = 0;
  protected $offset = NULL;
  protected $orderBy = NULL;
  protected $patterns = array();
  protected $prefix;  
  protected $selectList = NULL;
  protected $table;
  protected $tablePrefix = NULL;
  protected $unions = array();
  protected $valueStorage = array();
  protected $where = NULL;

  /**
   * @param object $db - The PDO database connection object
   * @param string $table - The name of the table
   * @param array $fields - The names of each field in the table
   * @param string $schema - The schema
   * @param $prefix - optional - A prefix for the table
   * @return The object for chaining 
   */
  function __construct(
    PDO $db,
    $table,
    array $fields,
    $schema,
    $prefix = NULL)
  {
    $this->db = $db;
    $this->prefix = $prefix;
    $this->tablePrefix = ($prefix) ? $prefix.$table : $table;
    $this->table = $table;      
    foreach($fields as $key)
    {
      $this->fields[$key] = NULL;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @param string $key - The table column name to retrieve 
   * @return mixed - The value of the key, if the key exists, FALSE otherwise
   */
  function __get($key)
  {
    return (array_key_exists($key, $this->valueStorage)) ?
        $this->valueStorage[$key] : FALSE;       
  }

  /**
   * @param string $key - The table column name to be assigned a value
   * @param $value - The value to assign to the key
   * @return boolean - TRUE if the key exists, FALSE otherwise
   */
  function __set($key, $value){
    if (array_key_exists($key, $this->fields))
    {
      $this->valueStorage[$key] = $value;
      return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Adds a value to be bound on query execution
   * @param mixed $value - The value(s) to be bound
   * @return string - The named value placeholder
   */
  protected function addBoundValue($value)
  {
    if (is_array($value))
    {
      $valueNames = array();
      foreach ($value as $val)
      {
        $this->numBoundValues += 1;
        $valueName = ':'.$this->numBoundValues;
        $this->boundValues[$valueName] = $val;
        $this->patterns[] = '#(\s'.$valueName.'[\s]?)#';
        $valueNames[] = $valueName;
      }
      return $valueNames;         
    }
    else
    {
      $this->numBoundValues += 1;
      $valueName = ':'.$this->numBoundValues;
      $this->boundValues[$valueName] = $value;
      $this->patterns[] = '#(\s'.$valueName.'[\s]?)#';
      return $valueName;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Adds space separators to each bound value
   * @return array - The spaced bound values
   */
  protected function getSpacedBoundValues()
  {
    $boundValues = ' '.implode(' | ', $this->boundValues).' ';
    return explode('|', $boundValues);
  }

  /**
   * @param string $alias - Sets the alias for the main table. Optional for
   * query build.
   * @return The object for chaining  
   */
  public function alias($alias)
  {
    $this->alias = $alias;
    return $this;
  }   

  /**
   * @var array $selectList - Used for determining which database fields
   * should be selected. Fields from joins may be included, but must include
   * either the full table name or alias as a prefix. 
   * @return The object for chaining
   */
  public function selectList(array $selectList)
  {
    foreach($selectList as $value)
    {
      $this->selectList[] = $value;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @param string $quotable - Escapes an input variable for use in an SQL
   * query. Returns the escaped string. Optional for query build.
   * @return The escaped input
   */
  public function quote($quotable)
  {
    return $this->db->quote($quotable);
  }

  /**
   * Joins will be added to the join array and processed in their array order
   * and use the ON syntax rather than USING. Optional for query build.
   * @param string $joinType - The type of join to be performed. Acceptable
   * values are 'left', 'right', 'inner', and 'full'
   * @param string $table - The name of the table to be joined with the
   * current table
   * @param string $column - The column(s) to be compared to the value
   * @param string $operator - The operator to be used in the comparison
   * @param string $value - The value to which $column is compared
   * @param string $tableAlias - optional - The alias of the joined table. If
   * not set, alias defaults to the table name
   * @return The object for chaining
   */
  public function addJoin(
    $joinType,
    $table,
    $column,
    $operator,
    $value,
    $tableAlias=NULL)
  {
    $joinAlias = ($tableAlias) ? $tableAlias : $table;
    $joinName = ($this->prefix) ? $this->prefix.$table : $table;
    $expr = "$column $operator $value"; 
    switch (strtolower($joinType)) {
      case "left":
        $this->joins[] = " LEFT JOIN $joinName AS $joinAlias ON $expr";
        break;
      case "right":
        $this->joins[] = " RIGHT JOIN $joinName AS $joinAlias ON $expr";
        break;                  
      case "inner":
        $this->joins[] = " INNER JOIN $joinName AS $joinAlias ON $expr";
        break;
      case "full":
        $this->joins[] = " FULL JOIN $joinName AS $joinAlias ON $expr";
        break;
      default:
        throw new Vm_Db_Exception(
          "'$joinType' is not a supported join type.");
    }
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a where clause.  Optional for query build.
   * @param string $column - The column(s) to be compared to the value
   * @param string $operator - The operator to be used in the comparison. 
   * @param mixed $value - The value to which $column is compared - If
   * multiple values are entered as an array, they will be wrapped in
   * parentheses, else use a string
   * @param string (optional) $antecedent - The operator preceding the WHERE
   * clause. Acceptable values are 'AND' and 'OR' 
   * @param string (optional) $paren - Adds a paren to the WHERE clause -
   * 'open', 'close', 'both'
   * @param boolean $caseSensitive - optional - Whether or not the clause
   * should be case sensitive, defaults TRUE. If FALSE, will use
   * UTF8_GENERAL_CI
   * @param boolean $bind - optional - Whether or not $value should be a
   * bound parameter, defaults TRUE. Use FALSE when $value is a subquery
   * @return The object for chaining
   */
  public function where(
    $column,
    $operator,
    $value,
    $antecedent = NULL,
    $paren = NULL,
    $caseSensitive = TRUE,
    $bind = TRUE)
  {
    $value = ($bind) ? $this->addBoundValue($value) : $value;
    $value = (is_array($value)) ? '( '.implode(', ', $value).')' : $value;
    $operator =
      ($caseSensitive) ? $operator : 'COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI '.$operator;
    switch ($paren){
      case 'open':
        $this->where[] = ($antecedent) ?
          " $antecedent ($column $operator $value"
          : " ($column $operator $value";
        break;
      case 'close':
        $this->where[] = ($antecedent) ?
          " $antecedent $column $operator $value)"
          : " $column $operator $value)";
        break;
      case 'both':
        $this->where[] = ($antecedent) ?
          " $antecedent ($column $operator $value)"
          : " ($column $operator $value)";
        break;                      
      default:
        $this->where[] = ($antecedent) ?
          " $antecedent $column $operator $value"
          : " $column $operator $value";             
    }
    return $this;       
  }

  /**
   * @param array $groupBy - The fields by which the result set should be
   * grouped. Optional for query build.
   * @return The object for chaining
   */
  public function groupBy(array $groupBy)
  {
    foreach($groupBy as $value)
    {
      $this->groupBy[] = $value;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Creates a HAVING clause.  Optional for query build. MUST be used in
   * conjunction with the GROUP BY clause
   * @param string $column - The column(s) to be compared to the value. Note:
   * The column is not a bound parameter in this clause
   * @param string $operator - The operator to be used in the comparison
   * @param string $value - The value to which $column is compared
   * @param string $antecedent - optional - The operator preceding the HAVING
   * clause. Acceptable values are 'AND' and 'OR'
   * @param string $function - optional - The SQL function to apply to the
   * column
   * @return The object for chaining 
   */
  public function having(
    $column,
    $operator,
    $value,
    $antecedent = NULL,
    $function = NULL)
  {
    $column = $this->addBoundValue($column);
    $column = ($function) ? "$function( $column)" : $column;
    $value = $this->addBoundValue($value);
    $this->having[] = ($antecedent) ?
      " $antecedent $column $operator $value" : "$column $operator $value";
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Orders the query.  Optional for query build
   * @param string $field - The field to sort by
   * @param string $sort (optional) - The sort type. Acceptable values are
   * ASC and DESC
   * @param boolean $caseSensitive - optional - Whether or not the ordering
   * should be case sensitive, defaults TRUE. If FALSE, will use
   * UTF8_GENERAL_CI
   * @return The object for chaining
   */
  public function orderBy($field, $sort = NULL, $caseSensitive = TRUE)
  {
    $sort = (strtolower($sort) == 'desc') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    $sort = ($caseSensitive) ? $sort : 'COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI '.$sort;
    $this->orderBy[] = ' '.$field." $sort";
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $limit - The limit of the result set.  Optional for query
   * build.
   * @return The object for chaining
   */
  public function limit($limit)
  {
    if (!is_int($limit))
    {
      throw new Vm_Db_Exception('Limit must be an integer');
    }
    $this->limit = ($limit != 0) ? $limit : NULL;
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * @param int $offset - The offset of the result set.  Optional for query
   * build.
   * @return The object for chaining
   */
  public function offset($offset)
  {
    if (!is_int($offset))
    {
      throw new Vm_Db_Exception('Offset must be an integer');
    }
    $this->offset = ($offset != 0) ? $offset : NULL;
    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Clears all class variables by setting them to NULL, allow class instance
   * reuse
   * @param boolean $clearBound - optional - Whether or not the bound
   * variables should be cleared, defaults TRUE
   */
  public function clear($clearBound = TRUE)
  {
    $this->valueStorage = NULL;
    $this->selectList = NULL;
    $this->alias = NULL;
    $this->joins = NULL;
    $this->where = NULL;
    $this->groupBy = NULL;  
    $this->having = NULL;           
    $this->orderBy = NULL;
    $this->limit = NULL;
    $this->offset = NULL;
    if ($clearBound)
    {
      $this->boundValues = NULL;
      $this->numBoundValues = 0;
    }
  } 

  /**
   * Compiles the given data into a select query and returns a result set
   * based on the query
   * @param string (optional) $mode - 
   * If set to 'single', returns a single result set which may be accessed
   * through magic methods.
   * 
   * Example: $user->name or $user->{'name'} 
   *
   * If set to 'assoc', will return the result set as an associative array,
   * which can be accessed through a foreach loop
   *
   * Example: foreach ($user->select("assoc") as $row)
   *          {
   *            echo "ID = ".$row['userId']."\t";
   *            echo "Type = ".$row['firstName']."\t";
   *            echo "Parent = ".$row['lastName']."<br>";
   *          }
   *
   * If set to 'num', will return the result set as a numerical array
   *
   * If set to 'obj', will return an anonymous object with property names
   * that correspond to the column names returned in your result set
   *
   * If set to 'lazy', will return a combination of 'both' and 'obj',
   * creating the object variable names as they are accessed
   *
   * If set to 'subquery', will wrap the query in parantheses and return it
   * for use in a subquery without executing it.
   *  WARNING: Bound parameters are not used for subqueries 
   *
   * If set to "count", will return the number of rows
   *
   * Example: $number = $user->select("count");
   *
   * If set to "union", will add the query to the unions array. Note: you
   * must reuse the object to use union.
   * 
   * Example:
   * 
   * $user = new Db_User($db);
   * 
   * //First Query
   * $user->where('lastName', '=', 'Jones');
   * $user->select('union');
   * 
   * //Second Query
   * $user->where('lastName', '=', 'Smith');
   * $user->select('union');
   * 
   * //Get union results (orderBy and limit are optional)
   * $user->orderBy('lastName', 'ASC');
   * $user->orderBy('firstName', 'ASC');
   * $user->limit(25);
   * $users = $user->select('assoc');
   *
   * If set to "debug", prints the compiled query
   *
   * Example: $user->select->("debug"); 
   *
   * If left unset, the default return set is 'both', which returns the
   * combination of both an associative array
   * and a numerical array
   * @param string $selectType - optional - 'DISTINCT' or 'ALL'. Note:
   * $selectType is ignored for the first select query in a set of unions
   * @return mixed - The query result set
   */
  public function select($mode=NULL, $selectType=NULL)
  {
    if ($selectType)
    {
      $type = ($selectType == 'ALL') ? ' ALL' : ' DISTINCT';
    }
    else
    {
      $type = NULL;
    }

    $selectList = ($this->selectList) ?
      ' '.implode(', ', $this->selectList) : ' *';
    $alias = ($this->alias) ? ' AS '.$this->alias : ' AS '.$this->table;    
    $joins = ($this->joins) ? implode('', $this->joins) : NULL;
    $where = ($this->where) ? ' WHERE'.implode('', $this->where) : NULL;

    if (!$this->groupBy)
    {
      $groupBy = NULL;
      $having = NULL; 
    }
    else
    {
      $groupBy = ' GROUP BY '.implode(', ', $this->groupBy);
      $having = ($this->having) ?
        ' HAVING '.implode('', $this->having) : NULL;
    }

    $orderBy = ($this->orderBy) ?
      ' ORDER BY '.implode(', ', $this->orderBy) : NULL;

    if ($this->limit)
    {
      $limit = ($this->offset) ?
        ' LIMIT '.$this->offset.', '.$this->limit
        : ' LIMIT '.$this->limit;
    }
    else
    {
      $limit = NULL;
    }

    if ((sizeof($this->unions) > 0) && ($mode != 'union'))
    {
      $query = implode(' ', $this->unions)."$orderBy$limit";
    }
    else
    {
      $query = "SELECT$type$selectList FROM "
        .$this->tablePrefix
        ."$alias$joins$where$groupBy$having$orderBy$limit";
    }
    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

    if ((is_array($this->boundValues))
      &&(!in_array($mode, array('subquery', 'union'))))
    {
      foreach ($this->boundValues as $name => $value)
      {
        $result->bindValue($name, $value);
      }
    }

    if (strtolower($mode) == "debug")
    {
      return preg_replace(
        $this->patterns, $this->getSpacedBoundValues(),
        $result->queryString, 1);
    }
    else if(strtolower($mode) == "subquery")
    {
      $this->clear(FALSE);
      return '('.$result->queryString.')';
    }
    else if (strtolower($mode) == "union")
    {
      $this->clear(FALSE);
      $this->unions[] = (sizeof($this->unions) >= 1) ?
        "UNION $selectType (".$result->queryString.')'
        : '('.$result->queryString.')';         
    }
    else
    {
      $result->execute();
      switch (strtolower($mode)) {
        case "assoc":
          return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        case "count":
          return count($result->fetchAll());
        case "num":
          return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        case "lazy":
          return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
        case "obj":
          return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        case "single":
          $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if (is_array($rows))
          {
            foreach(array_keys($rows) as $key)
            {
              $this->valueStorage[$key] = $rows[$key];
            }
          }
          return $rows;                   
        default:
          return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);  
      }
    }
  } 

  /**
   * The insert function inserts records into the database. Magic methods are
   * used to insert values into each field. Fields that are not assigned a
   * value will not be included in the compiled query.
   * Example usage: 
   *    $users = new Db_Users($db);
   *    $users->username = 'jDoe';
   *    $users->firstName = 'John';
   *    $users->{'lastName'} = 'Doe'; //An alternate syntax
   *    $users->{'age'} = 37;
   *    $users->insert();
   * @param string $mode - optional - 
   *  If set to 'debug', returns the compiled SQL query 
   * @return mixed - The last insert id if the query is successful, the
   * compiled query if mode is set to debug, 
   *  FALSE otherwise.
   */
  public function insert($mode=NULL)
  {
    $valueTypes = array('array'=>FALSE, 'single'=>FALSE);
    $arrayLength = 0;
    $fieldNames = array();
    $values = array();
    $params = array();

    foreach ($this->valueStorage as $name => $value)
    {
      $fieldNames[] = $name;
      if (is_array($value))
      {
        if (!$valueTypes['array'])
        {
          $valueTypes['array'] = TRUE;
        }
        if ($valueTypes['single'])
        {
          throw new Vm_Db_Exception(
          'Insert values must be either arrays '
            .'of the same length or a single value');
        }   
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($value as $inputValue)
        {
          $params[$i][] = '?';
          $values[$i][] = $inputValue;
          $i++;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (!$valueTypes['single']){
          $valueTypes['single'] = TRUE;
        }
        if ($valueTypes['array']) {
          throw new Vm_Db_Exception(
            'Insert values must be either arrays of the same length or a '
              .'single value');
        }
        $params[0][] = '?';
        $values[0][] = $value;
      }
    }
    $numInserts = 0;
    foreach ($params as $count=>$value)
    {
      $params[$count] = '('.implode(',', $value).')';
      $numInserts += 1;
    }
    $params = implode(',', $params);

    $numValues = sizeof($values[0]);
    $boundValues = array();
    foreach ($values as $value)
    {
      if (sizeof($value) != $numValues)
      {
        throw new Vm_Db_Exception(
          'Insert values must be either arrays of the same length or a'
            .'single value');
      }
      foreach ($value as $boundValue)
      {
        $boundValues[] = $boundValue;
      }
    }

    $query = 
      'INSERT INTO '
        .$this->tablePrefix
        .' ('
        .implode(',', $fieldNames)
        .') VALUES '
        .$params;

    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

    if (strtolower($mode) == 'debug')
    {
      $patterns = array();
      foreach ($boundValues as $value)
      {
        $patterns[] = '#\?#';
      }
      return preg_replace($patterns, $boundValues, $result->queryString, 1);
    }
    else
    {
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($boundValues as $value)
      {
        $boundValues[$i] = $boundValues[$i];
        $result->bindValue(($i+1), $boundValues[$i]);
        $i++;
      }
      $result->execute();
      return $this->db->lastInsertId() + $numInserts - 1;
    }
  } 

  /**
   * Updates a database field with values obtained from magic methods
   * representing the field names. 
   * Notes: Multiple table updates are currently not supported, nor are
   * ordering or limiting result sets due to DBMS syntax inconsistencies
   * @param string $mode - optional - If set to 'debug', returns the compiled
   * SQL query
   * @return int - The number of affected rows 
   */
  public function update($mode = NULL)
  {
    $fields = array();
    $boundValues = array();

    foreach (array_keys($this->valueStorage) as $field)
    {
      $fields[]= "$field=";
    }
    $parameters = implode("?, ", $fields).'?';

    $i = 1;
    foreach (array_keys($this->valueStorage) as $field)
    {
      $boundValues[$i]= $this->valueStorage[$field];
      $i++;
    }

    $where = ($this->where) ? ' WHERE'.implode('', $this->where) : NULL;
    $where = preg_replace('#(\s:[\w-]+[\s]?)#', ' ? ', $where);
    $boundValues =
      array_merge($boundValues, array_values($this->boundValues));
    $boundValues = $boundValues;

    $query = "UPDATE ".$this->tablePrefix." SET $parameters$where";
    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

    if (strtolower($mode) == 'debug')
    {
      $patterns = array();
      foreach ($boundValues as $value)
      {
        $patterns[] = '#\?#';
      }
      return preg_replace($patterns, $boundValues, $result->queryString, 1);
    }
    else
    {
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($boundValues as $value)
      {
        $boundValues[$i] = $boundValues[$i];
        $result->bindValue($i+1, $boundValues[$i]);
        $i++;
      }
      $result->execute();
      return $result->rowCount();
    }
  } 

  /**
   * The delete function deletes all rows that meet the conditions specified
   * in the where clause and returns the number of affected rows
   * @param string $mode - optional - Acceptable value is 'debug', which
   * prints the compiled query
   */
  public function delete($mode = NULL)
  {
    $where = ($this->where) ? ' WHERE'.implode('', $this->where) : NULL;
    $query = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->tablePrefix.$where;
    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);

    if (strtolower($mode) == 'debug') 
    {
      return preg_replace(
        $this->patterns,
        $this->getSpacedBoundValues(),
        $result->queryString,
        1);
    }
    else
    {
      foreach ($this->boundValues as $name=>$value)
      {
        $result->bindValue($name, $value);
      }
      $result->execute();
      return $result->rowCount();
    }
  }

  /**
   *  Description: Deletes all rows in the table, returns the number of
   * affected rows.
   * @return int - The number of affected rows
   */
  public function deleteAll()
  {
    $result = $this->db->prepare('DELETE FROM '.$this->tablePrefix);
    $result->execute();
    return $result->rowCount();
  } 
}
```

Maybe more to come...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, G. Qyy. The closing tag suggestion is useful, but I was hoping for a little different feedback than reformatting my code to a different style. If you could, would you please take a look at the last paragraph of what I wrote and perhaps address some of those questions?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't have a lot of time, and I can't afford to affect a lot of time if I don't know the licence of your code. If it's non-viral open source, it can really interest me, but if it's not...

Answer (score 5):

This code seemed pretty completed, tried using it on a small project. Then it hit me, there is no way for you to insert or select nulls properly. This has to be done with a specific bind param with PDO, example change in select method:

replace:

```
 $result->bindValue($name, $value
```

with:

```
if($value === null)
    $result->bindValue($name, null, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
else
    $result->bindValue($name, $value);
```

Another thing that I had to change was the requirement of the first constructor param to be PDO. Better to check if $db is PDO OR subclassed PDO with is_subclass_of() .

Comment: +1 on the NULL parameter binding, I'm not sure how I missed that. Could you expand on the PDO subclass comment? I'm curious as to what subclasses you would use as I just basically create a connection and pass it in.